# Execute a piece of code in one run without blocking it for other parallel threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

Let's say you have piece of code within a method, which doesn't use any critical resources, but you want to execute it in one run, because you want to make sure, that the code is executed as fast as possible without any pause due to scheduling.

If you  would take `lock` or `SemaphoreSlim` like bellow, the code within them will be blocked for every other thread which would run parallel and that would have a negative impact on performance. Of course `SemaphoreSlim` offers the possibility to define number of parallel threads, but I don't want to manage it by myself.

```
private readonly object myLock = new object();
lock (this.teamLock)
{
  // ... code
}
// 
private readonly SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);

public async Task LockAsync(Func<Task> worker)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        // ... code
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

Is there another way to make sure, that a code is executed in one run?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "executed in one run" ?

Comment: @fbv let's say the code i'm talking about has 10 lines. Once it starts with the first line, every other line should be executed in the same run  without any pause due to thread scheduling.

Comment: *"Of course `SemaphoreSlim` offers the possibility to define number of parallel threads, but I don't want to manage it by myself."* -- So you don't want to use a `SemaphoreSlim`? Why are you showing us how to use a `SemaphoreSlim` then? Why not show us some of the actual code that you would like to run?

Comment: You need some Real-Time OS for that to be possible for real... I'm not aware of any such OS that can run C# code... Can you clarify what OS you are targeting? Also while [edit] clarify how much effort you are willing to put in it - i.e. standard .Net GC also gives no control over when it is going to suspend threads meaning you need to find/build custom runtime... (Side note: it is very unlikely all such efforts will significantly improve performance, but that's for you to decide)

Comment: What do you mean by "in the same run"? Do you mean you want it to be single threaded? Synchronous? When you say "pause due to thread scheduling" do you mean you don't want the overhead of locking? Or you don't want the current thread to get yielded when you do asynchronous operations? Or that you want to force the operating system to not [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) to a different thread?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: you probably don't want to do it, and even if you do it's probably not woth it.

.NET threads are backed by OS threads, which use preemptive scheduling (and what you're asking is how to prevent preemption).

You can prevent other threads from running in the same app by suspending them. You'd need to drop down to the Win32 level in order to enumerate and suspend them. This can cause deadlocks if you want to run *managed* code, though, since the runtime in general assumes its threads are running. And there's still all the other threads from other apps.

Alternatively, if you're on Windows, you can raise your thread priority above the realtime level to avoid other threads getting dynamic priority boosts up to the same level as your thread. This is not recommended in general, though, and that goes double for managed code, for the same reasons as the deadlock above. The lack of dynamic boosting can cause deadlocks unless you are very careful. Use of realtime priorities require a complete understanding of all your dependencies and how they interact with a realtime priority thread.

So, while it's technically possible, it's quite a bit of work; and it really should not be managed code at all, since the runtime isn't designed for this. You would rewrite it as unmanaged code and then run it in a separate realtime process. And then verify that your dependencies will work as expected.

> you want to execute it in one run, because you want to make sure, that the code is executed as fast as possible without any pause due to scheduling.

Actually, what you *should* probably do is *lower* the priority, or just leave it the default. Dynamic priority boosts will automatically do what's best for the user. If anything, if you have a CPU-bound method that takes a noticeable amount of time, consider *lowering* the priority.